# Git and merge commits

Tags: git, workflows, branching

We have three branches:

- master
- staging
- dev

We *branch per issue* and each issue needs to go through testing and staging before being merged to master.

We branch feature branches from master and work on that feature.

- When ready for testing, we merge the feature branch into *dev* branch and TeamCity deploys to test environment.
- When ready for staging, we merge the feature branch into *staging* branch and TeamCity deploys to staging environment.

This involves a lot of merge commits on dev/staging branches, but very few on master, because the feature branches are always branched from master.

It's always a merge commit merged with a feature branch, so this is a merge from a merge, from a merge, from a merge, etc... So at any time TeamCity has 100+ pending changes, even though there is only 1 changed file when doing:

```
git diff dev~1...dev
```

Is there some way to minimize these merge commits?
Are we doing Git wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your workflow seems similar to the [“Git Flow”](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/), except that you start feature branches from `master`, whereas the Git Flow recommends branching from `dev`.

The idea is that `dev` closely reflects the current development state. Feature branches are supposed to be very short-lived (at most a couple of days of development). So when a feature is branched from `dev` and merged back into `dev` a day later, there will be very few conflicts. The `dev` branch would be used for Continuous Integration.

Git Flow then suggest branching a release branch (your `staging`) from the `dev` branch with multiple new features for QA and release preparation. On release, the code is merged into `master` so that `master` only contains fully tested published versions.

If we were to branch new features off `master` (i.e. the last published version), this would ignore all other features that have been merged into `dev` in the meanwhile. Although the diff between `dev^` and `dev` might be rather clean, there would be vast differences in the history:

```
             Am                                    B..Zm
  master ----x------------------------------------x
            / \                  \               /
 staging --x---|------------------|-------------x B..Zs
          /As  |         B  C..Y  |          Z /
     dev x-----|---------x--x--x--|-----------x
         A      \       /  /  /   |          /
featureB         x--x--x  .....   |         |
                 B1 B2 B3         |         |
  ...                             |         |
                                   \       /
featureZ                            x--x--x
                                    Z1 Z2 Z3
```

At merge `B` into `dev (A)` from `featureB (A As Am B1 B2 B3)`, the merge is rather clean. We then add a couple of other features `C` through `Y` into `dev`. After that, the history of `dev` looks like `A As Am B1 B2 B3 C1 C2 C3 ... Y1 Y2 Y3`. That still looks reasonable. Finally, we have the `featureZ` branch with the history `A As Am Z1 Z2 Z3` – note that `Am` is the nearest common ancestor commit of `dev` and `featureZ`.

The result is that at merge `Z`, we do not only test the effect of the commits `Z1 Z2 Z3`, but the effect of combining all the features `B1 B2 B3 C1 C2 ... Y2 Y3 Z1 Z2 Z3`.

The impact of this problem is reduced by frequent releases, so that the difference between `dev` and `master` is not that pronounced. However, this only makes the problem smaller, and does not solve it. TeamCity seems to realise that it's actually testing *all* the changes you made since you last merged into master, although these are not obvious in the branch history (since `dev` only contains merge commits).

I recreated the above branching example as an actual git repo, which is available as [latk/Git-Branching-Madness on GitHub](https://github.com/latk/Git-Branching-Madness). You can [look at the branch graph](https://github.com/latk/Git-Branching-Madness/network) online, or clone the repo and inspect it yourself, e.g.:

```
                          # tip: use "git log" with "--pretty=oneline"
$ git log featureZ        # history of featureZ
$ git log dev^            # complete history of dev before featureZ merge
$ git log dev^..dev       # what commits were added during the featureZ merge
$ git log master --graph  # display complete branching history
```

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you so much. The main problem is that we have to get different features (for different things) through testing and staging on a different pace. The *best* way to do that is to branch per issue and branch off from master. The down-side is that we have to keep stale branches *dev* and *staging*. But what alternatives do we have? Could you advice?

Answer (score 0):

Merging multiple times should not be a problem, and that's actually a normal way of working with Git.

Your team agreed to have a specific workflow. For small fixes, that may induce some overhead, compared to, e.g., merging directly on *master*. But this is okay, at least you have a process to perform continuous integration.

Now, I don't know TeamCity, but maybe you should focus on why it  has 100+ pending changes when the diff is actually small.

Comment: Ok thank you, but I guess these multiple pending changes are because of all these merge commits. So each time I merge something with a small diff, it triggers build/deployment on all projects instead of only the ones within the diff.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to frequently `git fetch` and `git merge` / `git rebase` master during development and qa in order to keep up with the changes and resolve conflicts as they happen.  I prefer git rebase which replays your changes on top of the lastest master